# Facebook canonical URL leads to no crawl at all

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, typo3, facebook-opengraph

I'm getting mad about a problem with our Facebook OG-Tags and neither google nore noone of my colleges could help me yet.
The problem is: we use a TYPO3 extension to generate Open Graphic Meta Tags exactly in the format Facebook demands in its best practise rules. So on our homepage the meta tags look like this:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1076994975680778" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Startseite" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.syncomnet.com/template/Resources/Public/images/icons/scn_facebook.png" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="250" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="250" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.syncomnet.com/home.html" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="SynComNet" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Personalplanung / Personaleinsatzplanung / Dienstplan mit PersPlanNet ERP Software von SynComNet" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="de_DE" />
```

The problem is, that the Facebook robot does not crawl the page at all. It results in a completely empty page after crawling our homepage as you can see here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.syncomnet.com%2Fhome.html

When I now copy the whole source of the homepage and paste it in a static test.html, the crawler gets the page. The only thing I have to change is the canonical URL in the og:url meta property...

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.syncomnet.com/test.html" />
```

... and the robot works without any problems.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.syncomnet.com%2Ftest.html

The problem is, that all the pages generated by the CMS are not crawled in any way. I also tested if the robots.txt is the problem by just allowing "/", but this has no impact. Where could the error be? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm now a bit closer: The facebook robot seems not to be able to handle gzip compression.

If i comment out the following section in my .htaccess...

```
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
        application/javascript \
        application/json \
        application/ld+json \
        application/manifest+json \
        application/rdf+xml \
        application/rss+xml \
        application/schema+json \
        application/vnd.geo+json \
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
        application/x-font-ttf \
        application/x-javascript \
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
        application/xhtml+xml \
        application/xml \
        font/eot \
        font/opentype \
        image/bmp \
        image/svg+xml \
        image/vnd.microsoft.icon \
        image/x-icon \
        text/cache-manifest \
        text/css \
        text/html \
        text/javascript \
        text/plain \
        text/vcard \
        text/vnd.rim.location.xloc \
        text/vtt \
        text/x-component \
        text/x-cross-domain-policy \
        text/xml
</IfModule>
```

... the facebook scraper works fine. Problem: this section is default by TYPO3. I'm now looking on my own how to add an exception for the facebook robot.